# Prevent content from narrowing when scrollbar appears

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm showing a scrollbar when user hovers a DIV. My problem is when the scrollbar appears, the content gets narrower.

Take a look to YouTube's menu (desktop website) to see what I'm looking for.

This is a sample code and the [link to codepen](http://codepen.io/EderIraizoz/pen/dMddOj) to see it working.

```
.scrollable{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 12px auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    &:hover{
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}

.content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
.scrollable{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 12px auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:hover{
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

}

You just have to set the `overflow-y: scroll` on hover so that it doesn't move your content.

Comment: It's the same. You can use "scroll" or "auto" in order to show the bar just in case that there is content inside.

Comment: I've just tested again on the codepen you provided and with my solution it works just fine, it doesn't move the content!

Comment: Oh yeah, that solves it in Chrome, but I'm developing it in Firefox, and obviously I need it for every browser ahah. Thanks anyway. I've solved it in an a little dirty way.